# Cakephp 3.4 JQuery , ajax and $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a big problem with Cakephp 3.4

This is my controller:

```
    //$id=$_POST["idString"]; ---- how can i do this in cakephp?
    $id = $this->request->data('idString');

    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Animal_id' => $id
        )
    ));
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
```

And this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".dropdown-item").click(function(){
         idString = $(this).attr("value");
        alert(idString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo  \Cake\Routing\Router::url(array('controller' => 'MyControllerName', 'action' => 'index')); ?>",
            data: "idString="+idString,
            success: function(result){
                $("#show").html(result);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

And this is my index :

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post):?>
    <li><?= $post->title, $post->text; ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>

<div id="show">
<--show id-->

</div>
```

And error that I have is

**Deprecated (16384): Controller::$layout is deprecated. Use $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout() instead. [CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 383]**

And it returns me one div 2 time.

Comment: you have set old way to set layout for your view controller but in 3.x, the new way is to use $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout(layout_file_path), just you need to update the layout setting

Comment: where should i update this layout? i mean the problem is that i have there an div "a" and inside of this div is something and after that i have this div "b " with id show and there he show me the what i need but the problem is that it returns 2 times . It return div "a" and div "b" with that what i need. It returns the same page 2 times one without that what i need and one time with that error and with what i need.Maybe the problem is in ajax?Sorry for my english. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! That will also answer your "_where_" question, as the stacktrace should show where the deprecated call is being made.

Comment: @ndm sorry i don't have any error in Logs its just this error that i said. Its looks like this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14eKU5qOqNRzIayLBA-6rjXlJZrsNZrDT) and if i press Lucky its returns this one [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nneXpLnrKJXVg_-XDhzsSs4ycM1e7qd6)

Comment: @SanjayKumarSingh look in the link you will understand what i mean.

Comment: Then you're maybe looking at the wrong place, or you've changed the default logging configuration, CakePHP by default logs all notices (in `logs/debug.log`). The notice output itself also contains the stacktrace (by default shown when clicking the link at the start of the message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cakephp 3.4 have in **src/Template/Layout/ajax.ctp** look there if don't have **$this->fetch('content');** if yes then delete it or comment.